# Setup U-boot to use DTB embedded into the binary

Tags: embedded, u-boot

I'm trying to configure U-boot to use a DTB that is embedded into the binary. I set `CONFIG_OF_EMBED` instead of `CONFIG_OF_SEPARATE` when building. The DTB seems to be properly embedded into the binary, since I can find it inside the binary, but eventually it fails on boot with a message:

```
No matching DT out of these options:
   Configuration to load ATF before U-Boot
No matching DT out of these options:
   Configuration to load ATF before U-Boot
mmc_load_image_raw_sector: mmc block read error
SPL: failed to boot from all boot devices
### ERROR ### Please RESET the board ###
```

I'm using a fork of Boundary Devices U-boot https://github.com/boundarydevices/u-boot-imx6 branch `boundary-v2018.07` on a Nitrogen8M board.

I boot the board using an i.MX8 bootable image created using `imx-mkimage`, which contains the a53 FIT image with ATF and U-Boot, separate SPL and HDMI/DDR firmwares.

What should I do to make U-boot recognize an embedded DTB, instead of a separate one provided in the FIT image?